# What exactly is REST agent vs REST client?

Tags: java, rest, client, agent

I have to write code to automatically create a JIRA based on some action performed in my workplace. The solution that my manager proposed is to create a JIRA creation agent. We are using REST architecture.

Last time I wrote a client. Now I have to write an agent. What I don't understand is the key and more like the technical difference between the two. Like how exactly these are different as for someone with very less experience with REST I feel hard to understand the core difference.

Do I have to code them in a different style? or what are some good practices to write these kinds of code?

I tried reading different blogs and related posts but couldn't find anything satisfactory to point out the differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be semantically different based on your company's internal linguistics, but typically it is as follows:

- REST Server is the software which provides the API which is exposed
- REST Client is the software which uses the REST Server's API to make requests and get the resulting information (usually JSON). This is more of an interface to make the requests
- REST Agent uses the REST Client to make the requests but actually uses the resulting JSON and processes it to perform some sort of action

However colloquially people use REST Client and REST Agent interchangeably. The main thing is delineation of who is providing information with API and who is making requests for information through an API.

EDIT: In order to clarify in your case the agent would be making a request through the API but would most likely be a PUT or POST request to create a JIRA issue.